Why were 2/4 of my mod flags declined despite all 4 answers being deleted?
A few hours ago, following guidance from Flag Duplicate Answers on the same Question, I raised moderator flags on 4 answers to How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?.
As you can see in the screenshot below, 2 of them were marked helpful and the other 2 got declined. When I noticed this, I started trying to figure out why they got declined but quickly realised all 4 answers were deleted.

For reference:

The first flag targeted this answer and links to this answer from 2011
The second flag targeted this answer and links to this answer from 2012
The third flag targeted this answer and links to this answer from 2012
The last flag targeted this answer and links to this answer from 2012

Now I'm a little confused, why would the 2nd and 3rd flags be helpful and the first and last declined while all flagged answers got deleted?

I can see that two of the answers were deleted directly by the moderator and two were deleted as plagiarism. My initial guess would be the deletion as plagiarism caused your flag to be declined but the moderators should be able to confirm.

Hmm, no it looks like I was wrong, 1 & 2 were deleted directly by the moderator and 3 & 4 were deleted as plagiarism. So that doesn't match up with my theory

Both declines are unfortunate mistakes.

this one was declined because I opened the link to the original post in a split screen: the page scroll didn't position exactly on the post you linked, so I incorrectly assumed you linked the wrong post.
this one was just a misclick: I intended to decline the flag mentioned above, but instead clicked on this one.

I still deleted the posts as soon as I realized I had mishandled the flags.
Unfortunately, moderators cannot change the outcome of a handled flag (except for red flags), so you undeservedly end up with 2 declined flags.
Sorry about that.

Alright, it didn't lead to a flag ban, I now know what happened and the answers have been deleted anyway so I'm happy with it :)

Probably a bit late, but I added this now as an item for consideration for the community asks sprint.

I'm getting inaccurate page scroll for these links too, it is indeed hard to tell which one the link refers to. Some manner of new bug?

Damn these new mods, where is the paper bag? :D

User interface error: it should never be possible to make a single misclick you can’t undo!

@Joymaker I definitely agree with you (and there are parts of the mod UI with that issue), though the more relevant issue here is that it can be difficult to tell from the mod UI which post (among multiple answers on a page) you're handling a flag on.
